# JQuery validate support for singular/plural forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery Validate plugin and am using it to show localized error messages, like shown here https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.format/

Since i wanted to make it a library i localized the error messages like this

```
$.extend($.validator.messages, {
   min: $.validator.format("enter at least {0} number") // in other language
});
```

I would like it so that it supports plural form, so that i can have:

1) enter at least 1 number

2) enter at least 2 numbers

What is the best way to do this? I want to avoid manipulating the message outside the validate method.

Edit: typo

Comment: You have a `}` where you should have a `)`, and you're missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: Noted and fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function where you conditionally construct the message...

```
 $('#myform').validate({
        ....
        messages: {
            foo: {
                min: function(param) {
                    var plural = (param > 1) ? "s" : "";
                    return "enter at least " + param + " number" + plural;
                }
            }, ....
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/p82ojnj6/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/p82ojnj6/2/)**

---

Alternatively,

```
$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    min: function(param) {
        var plural = (param > 1) ? "s" : "";
        return "enter at least " + param + " number" + plural;
    }
});
```

**DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/p82ojnj6/](https://jsfiddle.net/p82ojnj6/)**